# Scope a variable on stack in c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, memory, stack

Hi there i am new in c++ and my question is related to scope of a variable . Let me ask the quesion considering the code below

```cpp
#include <iostream>

static int* fun(){
  static int *ptr = new int(4);
  return ptr;
}

 static int * tun() noexcept{
   int f = 111;
   *(fun()) = f;
   return fun();
 }

 static int *sun(){
  return tun();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << (*sun()) << std::endl;
}
```

In the middle function `tun()` there is a variable named `f` and when the function return it is poped from the stack as per my knowledge . in this case the function return to `sun()` which is then called in main() and inside main it is giving me correct value of the variable decleard and initialized in function `tun()` . Can anybody explain this behaviour to me , i am a bit confused on it.

Comment: What do you expect and what do you observe? f doesn't exists out of `tun()`, but `fun()` has a static pointer having the same value as f.

Comment: "_In the middle function `tun()` there is a variable named `f` and when the function return it is poped from the stack as per my knowledge._" Yes, when `tun` returns, `f` is destroyed. Why does that matter? You don't store/return its address. All you do with it, is copy it's value, to the variable, that has `dynamic` storage duration, and return address of that.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `tun()` returns a pointer that is pointing on memory address of `f` when tun is no longer on the stack does'nt the memory got destroyed ? or ther is anything i am missing?

Comment: @UmarFarooq there is no pointer to `f` in your code.

Comment: @idclev463035818 what is `fun()` returning?

Comment: see my answer. It returns `ptr`

Comment: @UmarFarooq "_`tun()` returns a pointer that is pointing on memory address of `f`_" No it doesn't. You don't even take the address of `f` (`&f` would return memory address of `f`). You just copy the value, of it, to the memory location, returned by `fun`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `f` is gone, but its value has been stored in the `int` that the pointer returned by `fun` points to.
The code can be simplified to

```
#include <iostream>

int * tun() {
   static int* ptr = new int;
   int f = 111;
   *ptr = f;                  // copy value of f
   return ptr;                  
}                             // f is gone now, but who cares?


int main() {
  std::cout << (*tun()) << std::endl;
}
```

Its not clear what the code is supposed to do other than obfuscation, btw.

> tun() returns a pointer that is pointing on memory address of f when tun is no longer on the stack does'nt the memory got destroyed ?

No. There is no pointer to `f` in your code. This line

```
*(fun()) = f;
```

assigns the **value** of `f` to the `int` pointed to by the static pointer `ptr` returned by `fun()`.

It is similar to

```
int x = 0;
int* ptr = new int;
*ptr = x;            // assigns 0 to the int pointed to by ptr
std::cout << *ptr;   // prints 0
assert( ptr != &x);  // adress of x ist not ptr   !!!
```

Comment: `*(fun()) = f;` and this line is basically copying the value of f on a new location on memory?

Comment: i overcomplicated thing for nothing , thank a lot for explaining.

Comment: @UmarFarooq dont confuse a pointer with what it points to

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you assign the value to the pointer created on the heap in `fun`, the variable `f` no logner exists

```
  #include <iostream>

static int* fun(){
  static int *ptr = new int(4); // 4 stored inside pointer
  return ptr;
}// ptr still exists because it's heap allocated

 static int * tun() noexcept{
   int f = 111; //f holds value 111
   *(fun()) = f; // ptr now stores the value 111
   return fun();
 } // f gets destroyed, ptr still holds 111

 static int *sun(){
  return tun();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << (*sun()) << std::endl;
}
```